# qt on Mac: Form Layout fails to stretch horizontally

Tags: c++, qt

I'm still trying to do some pretty basic stuff with qt, and it's been a struggle. I'm specifically targeting for Mac. My current problem is getting the forms to not suck.

The simple problem. Create a new MainWindow app. Go into the Qt Creator (open Forms -> mainwindow.ui).

Drag 3 labels into place. Then I dragged 2 Line Edits and for fun, a Dial, but that part probably doesn't matter.

Click the main window and then tell it to use Form Layout. Within Qt Creator if I resize the window, my various line edits expand to fill the available space, exactly like I want.

Run the app. All the line edit fields are a fixed length, very short (if I don't override their minimum width), and do NOT resize as I resize the window.

Three quarters of the reason to use Form Layout is for resizing capability.

I've tried clicking on the central widget before setting to Form Layout: no change in behavior.

I *do* get reasonable behavior if I use a grid layout, although I have to add a vertical spacer at the bottom or my dial resizes crazily as I play with the window size.

So... Am I just doing something wrong with Form Layout? Or does it not work well on Mac and I should use Grid Layout instead?

I really miss Motif's XmFormLayout. It took time to set all the constraints, but I could make my forms do exactly what I wanted. Ah, but so 1990s.

Comment: It would also be nice if I can figure out how to NOT necessarily expand everything to full width. I have a few Line Edit widgets that I'd like to keep short. They're going to hold TCP port numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the panel to the right where you can see the objects, click the `centralWidget`. In the property panel, scroll down until you get to the layout properties of the form layout. Set the `layoutFieldGrowthPolicy` to `ExpandingFieldsGrow`.

By default, the line edits are not growing to fill the available space on macOS because they are not supposed to. This is some sort of macOS UI guideline. QFormLayout follows the platform conventions by default.

> It would also be nice if I can figure out how to NOT necessarily expand everything to full width. I have a few Line Edit widgets that I'd like to keep short. They're going to hold TCP port numbers.

For those, set the `Horizontal Policy` property (it's grouped inside the `sizePolicy` property group in the properties panel) of the affected line edits to something suitable. In this case, probably to `Fixed`, but look up the documentation first of what each setting does.

Comment: That did it! Thank you.

Comment: @JosephLarson No problem. One thing: I noticed that you never mark answers as "accepted" in your questions. If an answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted (including the cases where you answered your own question.)

Comment: Ah. How to do that wasn't obvious, and I didn't know I could. Thanks, Nikos.